# How in DJANGO create editable Select field?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-1.10

How in DJANGO create editable select field as in the picture below?

[image]

I used before **django-floppyforms** app in my project. It use `datalist` which is unflexibility in css styling. So is it possible replace `detalist` to `ul`, `li` elements?

**forms.py:**

```
CharacteristicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user_class = floppyforms.CharField(
       widget=floppyforms.TextInput(
          datalist=['A', 'B', 'C'],
          attrs={'autocomplete': 'off',}
       )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Characteristic
        fields = ('user_class')
```

Comment: (I'm not sure if this is the kind of help you're looking for). I've used an app called [django-forms-builder](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder). It allows the admin to create fields that are dropdown choices like that ideia in the image, and others like multi-select or checkboxes. Good luck

Comment: @S_alj Hello! It`s really interesting project  but thats not what I am looking for. Do you have any ideas?!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got other ideas for this :(